# How to interpret a lambda calculus expression?

Tags: lambda-calculus

say I am given the expression (i will refer to l as lambda):

lx.f1 f2 x

where f1 and f2 are functions and x suppose to some number.

how do you interpret this expression? is lx.(f1 f2) x the same as lx.f1 (f2 x)?

as an exemple, what will be the diffrence in the result of lx.(not eq0) x and lx.not (eq0 x)?
(eq0 is a function that return true if the parm equals 0 and not is the well known not function)

more formally T=lx.ly.x ,F=lx.ly.y ,not = lx.xFT and eq0 = lx.x(ly.F)T

Answer (score 2):

`f1 f2 x` is the same as `(f1 f2) x`. Function application is left-associative.

> is ln.(f1 f2) x the same as ln.f1 (f2 x)?

No, not at all. `(f1 f2) x` calls `f1` with `f2` as its argument and then calls the resulting function with `x` as its argument. `f1 (f2 x)` calls `f2` with `x` as its argument and then calls `f1` with the result of `f2 x` as its argument.

> ln.(not eq0) x and ln.not (eq0 x)?

If we're talking about a typed lambda calculus and `not` expects a boolean as an argument, the former will simply cause a type error (because `eq0` is a function and not a boolean). If we're talking about the untyped lambda calculus and `true` and `false` are represented as functions, it depends on how `not` is defined and how `true` and `false` are represented.

If `true` and `false` are Church booleans, i.e. `true` is a two-argument function that returns its first argument and `false` is a two-argument function that returns its second argument, then `not` is equivalent to the `flip` function, i.e. it takes a two-argument function and returns a two-argument function whose arguments have been reversed. So `(not eq0) x` will return a function that, when applied to two other arguments `y` and `z`, will evaluate to `((eq0 y) x) z`. So if `y` is 0, it will return `x`, otherwise `z`.

Comment: please expend about the later case and check edit i had a typo - more formally T=lx.ly.x ,F=lx.ly.y ,not = lx.xFT and eq0 = lx.x(ly.F)T.

Comment: "So (not eq0) x will return a function that, when applied to two other arguments y and z, will evaluate to ((eq0 y) x) z. So if y is 0, it will return x, otherwise z." and i also didnt get your point... with the given definitions of not,eq0,F, and T Is doing (not eq0) x the same as not (eq0 x)?

Comment: @OfekRon What I mean by that is that `(((not eq0) x) y) z` will evaluate to `((eq0 y) x) z`, which will evaluate to `x` if `y` is zero or to `z` otherwise. In contrast to that `((not (eq0 x)) y) z` will evaluate to `y` if `x` is zero and to `z` otherwise. So clearly there is a difference.

Comment: and what about the general case? if im given the expr lx.f1 f2 x, how should i interpret it?

Comment: @OfekRon As `lx. (f1 f2) x`. Function application is left-associative.